# How to solder two USB-C female PCBs together?

Tags: pcb, soldering, usb-c

I have two of these usb-c female sockets that I need to solder together to make a "gender changer"

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VJ944V2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VJ944V2)

Would I just solder the same pads from each board to each other? ex. A11 -> A11, A12 -> A12, so on.

Comment: Why don't you just buy one?

Comment: it has to fit in a very small space that I will 3D print a housing for

Comment: sounds like an X-Y problem ... why do you need a gender bender?

Comment: That board is bigger than the ones you can buy, and that's only one board, you'd need 2

Comment: Yes there are small ones, but they don't fit my specific needs for this project. A dongle will also not work. I do have two of these boards